# Is ssl needed between 2 ec2 instances over private port

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, ssl, servlet

I have a general security question related to data sharing between ec2 services. 
I have 2 ec2 instances in the same aws region which communicate with each other over a Java Socket on a specific port (lets say 27200). I've set the firewall on their security-group so that they only accept connections from each-other over this port and not from any other ip.
Is it needed to encrypt this connection with SSL to protect from someone listening in or is this impossible anyway?

Comment: Why aren't you using a VPC?

Comment: Besides for the above private connection, both servers offer public services on ports 8080 and 80 so I couldn't just isolate them behind a vpc.

Comment: That's what Elastic IPs are for!

Comment: why would the elastic IPs expose the services over 8080 but not the socket on 27200. Surely it makes them both vulnerable?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific general question, people on the big bad internets cant snoop this intra server communication. EC2 instance traffic within the same availability zone will go over Amazon's infrastructure. But as a general security principle, if you want traffic protected, encrypt it, always.

Comment: Does this mean that ssl would be to protect only from the case where attackers managed to hack into an amazon data centre and monitor its internal network?

Comment: If you dont know what you are doing, the most likely attack vector is your own machines.

Answer (score 1):

The notion of an internet-facing port being "private" is somewhat dubious. Without encryption, the traffic can be sniffed. Communications between servers could be vulnerable to a man in the middle attack. There are multiple methods by which an attacker can spoof an IP address, and this might allow them to send malicious packets to either of the servers.

Communications between servers might need be private, authenticated, or both. You *might* be able to secure communication with SSL/TLS. Although there are other cryptographic aproaches as well.